# "is" operator expected behavior in dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have slightly strange issue (I am probably missing something)
I decided to iterate over element tree in Flutter and had the following question:

```
if (element.widget.runtimeType == GestureDetector) {
        print('return true1');
}
if (element.widget.runtimeType is GestureDetector) {
        print('return true2');
}
```

The runtype of my widget  seems to be `GestureDetector` (that what I see in the debugger).
When I compare with `==` I see the *return true1* as expected.
BUT why when I compare it with `is` operator I don't see the *return true2*
That's kinda strange,
 why the `is` operator doesn't *return true2*? 
according to docs:
`The result of obj is T is true if obj implements the interface specified by T`
[link](https://dart.dev/language/operators)

Comment: Do not use .runtimeType.  Just "is".

Comment: Damn it I knew I was missing something silly , its too late I should look at it in the morning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

runtimeType is a property available to every object in dart. It has type of 'Type'.

So when you do

```dart
if (element.widget.runtimeType == GestureDetector) {
        print('return true1');
}
```

it is checking if runtimeType is GestureDetector where the value of `runtimeType` is GestureDetector but type is `Type`.

When you are doing,

```dart
if (element.widget.runtimeType is GestureDetector) {
        print('return true2');
}
```

It is checking of type of runtimeType is GestureDetector, which is not true as it is Type.

To check if widget is GestureDetector, you should be doing

```dart
if (element.widget is GestureDetector) {
        print('return true2');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should test the object itself, not its `runtimeType` getter. So it should be like this:

```dart
if (element.widget is GestureDetector) {
        print('return true2');
}
```

See the usage of Dart type test operators: https://dart.dev/language/operators#type-test-operators